# How can I remove the white space from pdf invoice on tax(VAT) and make it 2 columns

Tags: invoice, tax, pdf

I have a space on the row where the tax(VAT) is placed. On subtotal, total, etc and other fees the columns are ok, but for some reason on the tax row the placement is different and the pdf is printed with some white space, the vat has 1 column instead of 2. Or something like that. Where can i change that? Here is a screenshot[image]

Answer (score 0):

The two magento core classes responsible for displaying the tax summary in pdf are

> Mage_Tax_Model_Sales_Pdf_Tax
> Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Default

You can oerride these class files to display the tax info as you wish